# Is there a simple method to algebraically take a value outside of a trigonometric function argument

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Lets say I have a function $\sin(\frac{11\omega}{2})$ and I want to make the argument $\sin(\frac{\omega}{2})$,

I know that I cannot simply do this: $11*\sin(\frac{\omega}{2})$

So how would I go about removing the a constant from inside of a trig function?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want to do this?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials#Trigonometric_definition

Comment: @littleO I am working with fractions containing sin functions that can be converted into sinc functions (using as part of a Fourier Transform), however to successfully get a fraction containing sinc functions from sin functions, the top and bottom need to be divided by the same thing, so I want to make the top sin the same as the bottom sin.

Answer (score 0):

Using DeMoivre's Theorem:
$$\left(\cos \theta +i\sin \theta \right)^n=\cos n\theta +i\sin n\theta $$

We observe that the imaginary parts must be equal.

Case 1:n is odd.

$$\sin \left(n\theta \right)=\sum _{k=0}^{\frac{\left(n-1\right)}{2}}\binom{n}{2k+1}\sin ^{2k+1}\left(\theta \right)\cos ^{\left(n-\left(2k+1\right)\right)}\left(\theta \right)$$

Case 2: n is even
$$\sin \left(n\theta \right)=\sum _{k=1}^{\frac{\left(n\right)}{2}}\binom{n}{2k-1}\sin ^{2k-1}\left(\theta \right)\cos ^{\left(n-\left(2k-1\right)\right)}\left(\theta \right)$$

Answer (score 0):

You can trade $\cos nx$ and $\sin nx$ for polynomials in $\cos x,\sin x$. Similarly, you can trade the powers $\cos^n x,\sin^n x$ for linear combinations of $\cos kx,\sin kx$.

I am not sure that this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Building on @YvesDaoust 's answer, and from [a section of Wikipedia's trigonometric identities page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Angle_sum_and_difference_identities), we have:

$$\sin{(a \pm b)} = \sin{(a)}\cos{(b)} \pm \cos{(a)}\sin{(b)} \tag{1}$$
$$\cos{(a \pm b)} = \cos{(a)}\cos{(b)} \mp \sin{(a)}\sin{(b)} \tag{2}$$

so that you could split the trig that way.  These, especially (1), can be used to derive the double angle formula

$$\sin{(2a)} = 2\sin{(a)}\cos{(a)} \tag{3}$$

You can also consider the multiple angle formula found on the same page [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Sine,_cosine,_and_tangent_of_multiple_angles).  It's basically an extension of (3).